# Exporting appengine logs from non default version

Tags: google-app-engine

We are using a google Appengine backend with multiple versions running (the non default versions are for testing and internal purposes). The logs from the default version is exported to a GCS bucket. My problem is that I would like to also export the logs from one of the non default versions to GCS, but cannot figure out how to do that. Is this even possible? Cannot find any settings for it.

Comment: Hi andreas. I don't think there's a way to do this. Couldn't you change the default version, do the export, then bring back your default version to the one you need? Definitely not ideal, but depending on your traffic pattern, it may still be doable.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible, the default version is constantly handling requests from customers, so disabling that would not be a good idea.
I guess the non ideal thing here maybe is our setup with several versions of the application used at the same time. But it would be so nice to solve this without having to redo out setup of the infrastructure

Comment: I definitely get that, and right now it's unfortunate there is no solution for you. I believe this is a very valid feature request, so I invite you to file it here : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list. There is no guaranteed delivery, so this will not solve your immediate issue, but it may provide a solution in the longer run.

Comment: I took a step back and reviewed the server setup anyway and got rid of the need for this. Not sure if I think it is a valid request to have it fixed or just an issue due to a broken setup from my side.

Comment: As this seems not currently possible, @Patrice care to post this an answer as is the technically the correct answer to the question?